# Node *next in linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am a newbie in data-structures and algorithms. I came across the following code

```
typedef struct node                                                
    {                                                               
          int data;            
          node *next;            
    };
```

Can anyone please tell me why are we declaring node *next? Can't *next be declared as int *next?

Comment: This comes down to understand what the purpose of next is. What made you think next could be an int?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because you'll want to be able to do `n->next->next->next...` and so on.

`next` needs to point to another `node`, not an `int`, else you won't be able to see the next `int` after that (you cannot do `(aInt)->next`, can you?)!

You can see `node`s as small boxes that contain a `int` (or any other data) and a reference to the next little box. If you point directly to the data, you won't be able to get the box after that (it's just dumb data!) - you need to point to boxes (`node`s)!

Here's an image that might help to see what I mean (credits goes to [Virginia Tech](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/csonline/DataStructures/Lessons/OrderedListImplementationView/index.html)):
[image: Here's a little image explaining it]

Comment: ok. So basically node*next is used to point to next data? Am i right?

Comment: Exactly. It is used to point to the next node. You can see nodes as small boxes that contain a `int` and a reference to the next little box.

Comment: @loldop Sorry, I didn't do it. :( I don't want to take credit for it. Editing the post so this is clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but it won't help you write a linked list. `node *next` ensures that you've a variable next which is a pointer to the `node`. `int *next` would mean that next would point to an integer and not the `node`, won't give you the linked list, which is what you seem to be looking for.