# Can somebody explain what node*next means in the below code in C++?

Tags: pointers, linked-list

```
class node{
  public:
    int data;
    node* next;
    node(int val){
      data=val;
      next=NULL;
    }
};
```

What does `node*` next means? What are class pointer?

Comment: `node * next` defines a member for each future instance of `node`, which can be `NULL` (or better: `nullptr`) or a reference (pointer) to an instance of `node`. This allows to create a chain of node instances, where each one links via this pointer to the next. The last one will typically have `nullptr` for `next`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node \*next in linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103146/node-next-in-linked-list)